# Consecutive calls to chrome.extension.sendMessage()

Tags: asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, storage

I am writing an extension, where I want my own cookies store `mycookies` in `background.js` which stores domain, path, key and flags. In my `background.js`, when an HTTP response is received, I call `chrome.extension.sendMessage()` for each Set-Cookie header of the the response. So each response call this function many times within few m-seconds. After the response, only the last one or two cookies are stored, the rest are lost.

I did the following experiment. I connected a button with the function `update_mycookies`. A click on button calls the function immediately and displays the content of `mycookies` after 2500ms. If I read the store after 2500ms, all four cookies are there if I introduce the delays (as below) in `update_mycookies` but if I remove the delays, only the last one or two cookies are updated, the rest are lost. The `chrome.extension.sendMessage` is using `chrome.storage.local.set(). I want my store must be updated with all the cookies in response.

```
function update_mycookies(){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({"cdomain":".google.com", "path":"/", "key":"PREF"});
    setTimeout(function() {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({"cdomain":".google.com", "path":"/", "key":"NID"});}, 1000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({"cdomain":".google.it", "path":"/", "key":"PREF"}); }, 1500);

    setTimeout(function(){
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({"cdomain":".google.it", "path":"/", "key":"NID"}); }, 2000);
}
```

The `onMessage` listenr is the following:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(  
  function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
 if (request["cdomain"] && request["path"] && request["key"]) {
       chrome.storage.local.get("mycookies", function (items) {
         if (items["mycookies"]) {
          var found = false;
           var entries = items["mycookies"].split(";");
           entries.forEach (function (entry) {
            var dk = entry.split(",");
             if (dk[0] == request["cdomain"] && dk[1] == request["path"] && dk[2] == request["key"])
               found = true; 
           });
           if (!found)
             chrome.storage.local.set({"mycookies": items["mycookies"] + ";" + request["cdomain"] + "," + request["path"] + "," 
               + request["key"] });
         }
        else 
     chrome.storage.local.set({"mycookies": request["cdomain"] + "," + request["path"] + "," + request["key"] });
      }); 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Could you please also include your code of the chrome.extension.onMessage event listener?

Comment: @方 觉 onMessage listener added

Comment: chrome.storage.local.get is asynchronous. When you send three messages all at a time, chrome.storage.local.set in the callback may not have been called when the second or third chrome.storage.local.get is called.

Comment: @方 觉 I was in doubt about this. Can you please suggest me the solution/alternative way to solve my problem? When response is received, I want to update my store with all cookies received.